# Symfony 2 validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

i have a question regarding symfony 2 validation via an Entity and a validation configuration file. Here is the explanation of the problem.

I have an entity for the users account settings which has 5 properties - subdomain, email, oldPassword, password and new_password_confirmed.

My configuration file is as follows:

```
Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\AccountSettings:
properties:
    email:
        - Email: ~
    oldPassword:
        - Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword:
            message: "Wrong value for your current password"
constraints:
        - Expression:
            expression: "this.passwordMatch()"
            message: "Passwords don`t match"
```

My question is - How can i use this entity for validation and choose to perfom the validation only on a certain item, for example the email .
Here is my code in the moment for this validation, but it requires all the validation rules to be met in order the validation to be successfull:

```
    $accountSettings = new AccountSettings();
    $accountSettings->email = $_POST['email'];
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($accountSettings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should then use [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups). It allows you to do,

```
Backend\Builders\PageBundle\Entity\AccountSettings:
properties:
    email:
        - Email: { groups: [xxx_group] }
    oldPassword:
       # ...
```

---

```
$errors = $validator->validate($accountSettings, array('xxx_group'));
```

Check [the example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) provided in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).